# Ionic app crashes when targeting API Level 28

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, background-process, foreground-service

So, I have an Ionic app which I need to upgrade to target API Level 28 to conform to the new Playstore regulations. I'm using this in my `config.xml`:

`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />`

The problem is that with this update, the app crashes everytime I use the `BackgroundGeolocation` plugin. I found out that I should use this code in my `config.xml` file, but it didn't changed anything:

`<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/uses-permission" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
</edit-config>`

Is there any way to do this update without upgrading to `Ionic 4`?